# How will I get my website preloader to appear only once until the user clears their cached?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a preloader to my site and it's working well. It's only attached to the home page, however, whenever I go back to the home page, the preloader will appear again. I would like it to happen that once the site (home page) is cached already, the preloader will not appear.

[Here is my site](http://www.healthtravelexpo.com)

And here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 $(window).load(function() { 
 $("#status").fadeOut(); 
 $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); 
 })
 //]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: You can create a cookie after the preloader is created. Then only call the preloader method if the cookie does not exist.

Comment: Depending on the browsers you are targetting, you could also write to a localStorage variable and show your loader when it is not present or false

Comment: Hi Philip, I would need to research for that cookie. That looks like the thing for this job. @c_ckick, localStorage sounds new to me. I would also need to research for that. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: I've created a cookie method that concists of 10 lines only which is easy to use, although I will only be able to post the coding in about 6 hours as I don't have it with me. Otherwise you can try using @I_Debug_Everything code found below. I personally don't like w3schools as I've had some problems with provided coding.

Comment: Hi Philip, can you still post that code?

Comment: I've found that my methods are similar to what @I_Debug_Everything has posted.

Answer (score 0):

I referred this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
You can use javascript function inorder to achieve that

**Demo:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

 //<![CDATA[
 $(window).load(function() { 

if(!getCookie("loaded")){
```

**Edit**

```
 //Show element only if the cookie is absent.
 $("#preloader").show();
 $("#status").fadeOut(); 
 $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); 
//property name , value and no of expiration days
setCookie("loaded",true,365);
    }
else{
    $("#preloader").hide();
    $("#status").hide();
}

 })
 //]]>
 </script>
```

**Edit:**
you can also initialize the element to be hidden by default by setting `display:none` of your **preloader** element. Then via javascript will only show the element if the cookie is not present.See my edits in code.

Comment: Hi @I_Debug_Everything, this seems to work but the image (the preloader image) is left hanging in the middle because in my HTML, just below the body tag, i have this div which allows me to show the preloader image.

How can I do it so that when the coookie is set, the div also is disregarded?

    <div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

Comment: I have updated my answer, not sure if it is the best possible way but it should work. See the else part

Comment: Hi @I_Debug_Everything, when I put the else, like in your code, the preloader still appears only, it doesn't have the fadeout effect. But still there. However, when I remove the else part, the thing is just stuck there. It seems that its' working without the else, but it can't hide the preloader.

Comment: is your preloader wrapped in some other element? would you mind checking it.

Comment: Still doesn't work bro. the preloader is just below the body tag and is not enclosed to any divs. like this:

    <div id="preloader">
      <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

Comment: i tried to figure out what the problem might be but i think i am giving the right solution. Would you mind clearing your browser cache?